# How to read name of files in a directory, and counting the words and line

Tags: c, file

Hello I have to list the files in a directory and for each file i would count number of words and lines. The problem is on the opening of file beacuse the file pointer is NULL, always.
the files are located in this folder: myfolder, the program too.

The program is launched from here: otherthings/myfolder/readfiletest.c

```
int main(void)
{
    int word_count = 0, line_count = 0,in_word = 0;
    char ch;
    DIR *d;
    FILE *fp;
    char path[2100];
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir("myfolder");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
            
            strcpy(path,"myfolder");
            strcat(path,"/");
            strcat(path,dir->d_name);
            fp = fopen(path, "r");
            int i =0;
            /*while(path[i]){
                printf("%c",path[i]);
                i++;
            }*/
            if(fp == NULL) {
                 perror("Could not open the file");
                }
             while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
                if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0' || ch == '\n') {
                    if (in_word) {
                    in_word = 0;
                    word_count++;
                }

            if(ch = '\0' || ch == '\n') line_count++;

            } else {
                in_word = 1;
             }
             fclose(fp);
    }

        }
        printf("Number of words: %d.\n", word_count);
        printf("Number of lines: %d.\n", line_count);
        closedir(d);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Eited code, my output is:
mytext.txt
..
.
Segmentation fault ( i can't report the exception beacuse im running in a container that contains an envoironment for OpenMPI, so the error is mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node 979208abf4bc exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault)
).

Comment: `"myfolder"` seems to be on a visible path, so would one file there be `"myfolder/mytext.txt"`, not `"mytext.txt"`?

Comment: so I should open in read myfolder/mytext.txt? @WeatherVane

Comment: That would be the implication: try constructing the name from the folder and the file name.

Comment: I tried your solution and i change the code as below:  strcpy(path,"myfolder");
            strcat(path,"/");
            strcat(path,dir->d_name);
            fp = fopen(path, "r");                But I get segmentation fault

Comment: How is `path` defined in your change above?

Comment: char path[100]; and ater in this i do strcpy strcat strcat

Comment: Use `perror` when fopen fails so that you can see the exact error you have. It is usually very useful :-)

Comment: @fpiette there is no error for the opening of the file i guess, i swap my printf with perror but, the same: segmentation fault. Not for the opening, i think the problem is after the open.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68225197/edit) your question to add the code you have right now.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int` not `char`. It's a frequent beginner mistake to think "character" means `char`. So you need `int ch`.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah tried, but the same problem, and how i should compare int ch with '\t' or other?

Comment: Well `'\t'` is type `int` *not* `char`. I don't think  it's the reason for the segfault though.

Comment: If you are adding `printf` cues to track the progress, add `fflush(stdout)` after every one of them.

Comment: What is needed though, is the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it does exhibit the behaviour described, and so the exact code can be tried by contributors. The latest edit introduced a typo, and once that happens the rest of the supposed code is worthless.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok done, i see that he go in the else 1 time, and after he gives me seg fault. The file contains: "hello hello hello"

Comment: Not being pedantic, but you need to `#include <stdio.h>` and `string.h` and maybe some others too. Don't make us assume a single thing.

Comment: Ah! `fclose(fp);` is *inside* the `while` loop that is reading from it. Please format  code properly, to make things like this more obvious.

Comment: @WeatherVane ops, sorry you're right. But he reads the .c file too, there is a way to don't read this file?

Comment: Please ask another question. This site isn't a rolling "fix my code" place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your `while` loop

```
        while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0' || ch == '\n') {
                if (in_word) {
                in_word = 0;
                word_count++;
            }

        if(ch = '\0' || ch == '\n') line_count++;

        } else {
            in_word = 1;
        }
        fclose(fp);
}
```

with `fclose(fp);` *inside* the loop that is reading from it. When formatted, your code is

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0' || ch == '\n') {
        if (in_word) {
            in_word = 0;
            word_count++;
        }

        if(ch = '\0' || ch == '\n')
            line_count++;

    } else {
        in_word = 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Now, you can see that `fclose(fp);` needs to be moved down out of the loop.

Comment: Even though for regular text files ch will never be zero,`ch = '\0'` is suspicious. That is, in the final block of code in your answer. I'd be sad if someone copied this code without thinking about all the "rolling" problems.